# Handsontable - enable filter plugins for certain columns

Tags: handsontable

I am using Hands On Table, and you can enable the filter plugin by setting in the config `dropDownMenu:true` and `filters:true`. However, is there any way to restrict the filtering to specific columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually not supported in handsontable but in this issue [(link)](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3577), someone write the code for this functionality.